# Quotation marks in HTML

Tags: html, quotations

ok so I was wondering what the purpose of quotation marks were in this code:

```
style= "color:orange;font-size:20;"
```

Every time I use autocomplete it does

```
style= ""
```

What is this? what is it purpose?

Sorry about the weirdness, still new to using code blocks.

Comment: This question is being downvoted because, to be honest, this is a very basic entry-level 101 question about the very syntax of of HTML.  This question isn't a "I'm having a problem with something..." type question.  Instead, you are asking a "Teach me HTML" which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no basic research.

Answer (score 4):

Quotes are there to indicate what the attribute's value is. In this case, the `style` attribute's value is `color:orange;font-size:20;`. If you don't know that though, I recommend looking up a HTML tutorial site. This is literally one of the very first things you learn in those.

Comment: Thank you, and I will, I just learn better by jumping in, and asking questions as I go along, then when I get the basic do the tutorials(with an understanding of what they're saying) and learn what I missed.

Comment: @Katanza This is a fast way to start developing bad habits early. Hands on is a great approach but you should really help yourself out by following a few basic tutorials at least to begin.